# Where to find the default status codes file for Apache in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to customize all the status codes (error codes) in Apache - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

The error message content I get on the browser for the error code 414 is:

**Request-URI Too Large**

The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.

I went through the file:

```
/etc/apache2/conf.d/localized-error-pages
```

to see the default file which shows this error, I found the below line:

```
ErrorDocument 414 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE.html.var
```

When I go through the file

```
/usr/share/apache2/error/HTTP_REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE.html.var
```

I didn't find the same message viewed on the browser! How come? Where I can find the default message to edit it? I edited the above file and nothing changed on the browser!

One more thing, how can I customize this error to fit two different websites on the server (each website has different custom_error_414 page)

**UPDATE:**
I removed the comments on the file localized-error-pages but the output didn't change, when I add any path in the file localized-error-pages like:

```
ErrorDocument 414 /var/www/myproject/error.php
```

it doesn't work, but when I add a normal string like:

```
ErrorDocument 414 "Long Request"
```

it does work! Please provide some codes and details on how to fix this issue and how to customize the 414 error for two websites.

**UPDATE**

Below is the output of
`wget -O- -S ...`

```
--2014-05-02 21:02:26--  http://localhost/error//HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED.html.var
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:80... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Fri, 02 May 2014 21:02:26 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 1
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

2014-05-02 21:02:26 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

One more thing, I put the error page in /var/www/myproject/error.php but when I tried:

```
ErrorDocument 414 /var/www/myproject/error.php
```

It didn't work :( While

```
ErrorDocument 414 "Sorry, request is too long"
```

Worked out!

How come? Why it doesn't redirect me to the error page?

One more thing, I need to make for two websites two different pages, how can I achieve:

```
ErrorDocument 414 sites1 ==> /var/www/myproject1/error.php
ErrorDocument 414 sites2 ==> /var/www/myproject2/error.php
```

I want to put the error pages on my /var/www/project folder

I would greatly appreciate if you can send me direct steps to follow as I am not experienced system admin and I can't find documentation about this on the internet, it is very poor.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the detailed answer, I have followed your steps but I have minor issues would appreciate your input.

a. Below is the configuration file for the errors `/etc/apache2/conf.d/localized-error-pages`

```
    
      
        
            #Alias /error/ "/usr/share/apache2/error/"
            
                Options IncludesNoExec
                AddOutputFilter Includes html
                AddHandler type-map var
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                LanguagePriority en cs de es fr it nl sv pt-br ro
                ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
            
            ErrorDocument 404 /error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var
            ErrorDocument 405 /error/HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.html.vr
            ErrorDocument 408 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_TIME_OUT.html.var
            ErrorDocument 410 /error/HTTP_GONE.html.var
            ErrorDocument 411 /error/HTTP_LENGTH_REQUIRED.html.var
            ErrorDocument 412 /error/HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED.html.var
            ErrorDocument 414 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE.html.var
```

b. I have enabled the 3 mods successfully.

c. I have copied:

`cp -R /usr/share/apache2/error/include /usr/share/apache2/include_site1` 
also 
`cp -R /usr/share/apache2/error/include /usr/share/apache2/include_site2`

d. In `site1` configuration in the page: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1`, I added:

`Alias /error/include "/usr/share/apache2/error/include_site1"`
`Alias /error/ "/usr/share/apache2/error/"`

e. `apache2ctl configtest`
Syntax OK

f. Reloaded the Apache, loaded without errors.

g. `wget -O- ..../error/HTTP_REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE.html.var` result is:

`` HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 223 [text/html]
Saving to: `STDOUT' ``

0% [                                                                                                                               ] 0           --.-K/s              [an error occurred while processing this directive]

```
The length of the requested URL exceeds the capacity limit for
    this server. The request cannot be processed.
```

[an error occurred while processing this directive]
100%[==============================================================================================================================>] 223         --.-K/s   in 0s

2014-05-04 17:48:33 (73.1 MB/s) - written to stdout [223/223]

h. Tried from the browser: `.../error/HTTP_REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE.html.var`
The same result as step 8 but the in the browser

i. When I try placing huge request in the browser like: `...../site1/sj7xlekrjsuglkehgigl.........,` 
I get empty output on the browser and in the network (F12) I can see 414 error status

How can I get this working? I need to give the code 404 for the 414 error and I need to use (include) the customized PHP pages on each website, which is
 `/var/www/site1/not_found.php`

**Edit 2**

I have added the below in sites available, but if I put long URL in browser, it doesn't redirect me to index.php nor to not_found.php page. **I need the long URL error (414) to direct me to 404 page :(**  I am really upset I can't find any help online. Error like 414 doesn't work like 404 easily, they built inside the system.

404 is very easy for me! But can't configure 414!!!

`ErrorDocument 404 /not_found.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

For example in sites-available the below doesn't work

ErrorDocument 414 /not_found.php

Answer (score 0):

Localized error messages are commented out in the default configuration.  You need to modify the `localized-error-pages.conf` file to enable the localized pages.  It is dependent on a number of modules being enabled.

If you are getting the files from the error directory, these files contain the response in multiple languages.  The content is determined based on the language(s) specified by the browser.  The header and footer are found in the include sub-directory.

Some browsers may use their own message in place of the server provided content.  Try using `wget`, `curl`, or `w3m` to test the output.  Once you are getting a correct message with one of them try using your browser.  Your browser may also have cached a response from a previous attempt, so you may need to force a refresh or flush the browser cache.

You can use different files for different sites or use server side includes to add site specific information.

The URL for the error pages should be in the form `http://www.example.com/error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html`.

EDIT: I am working from the install on Ubuntu 13.10 but the configuration has been quite stable over the years.  The provided pages require the alias, include, and negotiation.  I believe you need a restart to enable them if they are not already enabled.  The `a2enmod` command should tell you if they are already enabled.

Try using `wget -O- -S http://localhost/error//HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED.html.var` to verify the page can be served.  Until that works, the error page will not be served.   Then try using `w3m http://localhost/failing_URL` to test the output.  The error pages don't seem to be served if the client doesn't provide the language negotiation information.

The directory `/usr/share/apache2/error/include` should have the header and footer for the message.  You can use `Alias` directives to change the directory these files are read from to customize by site.  You need to ensure this directive occurs before the `Alias` directive for the `/error` directory.  Doing the aliasing in the site configuration would be appropriate.   Something like:

```
Alias /error/include/ "/var/www/site/error/include/"
Alias /error/ "/usr/share/apache2/error/"
```

You may want to verify your configuration with `apache2ctl configtest` to see if you get any warnings.  Check the `/var/log/apache2/errorlog` file for related messages.  If you have it enabled, the sever-info page is also helpful in diagnosing what is happening.

EDIT:  This is an extracts of my localized-error-pages configuration with several error documents omitted.  This can likely be common for both sites as the content you need to modify should be in the /errors/include

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  <IfModule mod_include.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        #Alias /error/ "/usr/share/apache2/error/"
        <Directory "/usr/share/apache2/error">
            Options IncludesNoExec
            AddOutputFilter Includes html
            AddHandler type-map var
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            LanguagePriority en cs de es fr it nl sv pt-br ro

            ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
        </Directory>
        ErrorDocument 404 /error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var
        ErrorDocument 405 /error/HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.html.vr
        ErrorDocument 408 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_TIME_OUT.html.var
        ErrorDocument 410 /error/HTTP_GONE.html.var
        ErrorDocument 411 /error/HTTP_LENGTH_REQUIRED.html.var
        ErrorDocument 412 /error/HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED.html.var
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>:
```

Verify the required modules are loaded with the command:

```
sudo a2enmod negotiation include alias
```

If should tell you if if loaded any modules in which case you will need to restart apache.

Copy the error/include sub-directory for each of the sites.  Edit the files in these files to modify the error pages.

```
 sudo cp -R /usr/share/apache2/error/include /usr/share/apache2/include_site1
 sudo cp -R /usr/share/apache2/error/include /usr/share/apache2/include_site2
```

Add the following lines to the site configurations (change site1 to site2 for the second site):

```
Alias /error/include "/usr/share/apache2/error/include_site1"
Alias /error/ "/usr/share/apache2/error/"
```

Check the configuration and reload apache:

```
sudo apache2ctl configtest
sudo apache2ctl reload
```

Verify the pages load.  If these fail, you need to resolve this issue.

```
wget -O- http://site1/error/HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED.html.var
wget -O- http://site2/error/HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED.html.var
```

Try locally using `w3m` (text browser) as `wget` does not get served the error page.

```
w3m http://site1/nopage
w2m http://site2/nopage
```

If this works try with a browser.  You may want to try setting your preferred language to something other than English to see how the language variance works.

EDIT2: You can handle the errors in your php index page like WordPress does. This is done with rewrite rules to pass any missing URLs to the index page.  (You need to handle the 404 condition in the index page.)   I haven't tested any cases not generated within WordPress.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

If you want to use your own PHP error pages skip the all above steps and just add error document settings in your pages.   It appears you just want to direct apache2 to use you pages, not get it to sever the apache2 custom pages. (You can use the same document for multiple errors.) Add  lines like this to your site specification.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /not_found.php
```

You can read and set the status of the page.  (Set the status before outputting anything else as you need to set the status before the headers are written.)  From the PHP documentation on [http response code:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)

```
<?php
 http_response_code(404);
?>
```

Comment: thanks but the page is localized-error-pages, not localized-error-pages.conf. Please see my update on the question. Also, more than one browser having same message. Would you please give me details and show some codes on how to have to different customized pages for 2 websites? I am really lost and it doesn't work!

Comment: @moderns I've updated with more information.  Work step by step, get the pages working as pages, then move on to getting them displayed.  Read the comments in the the `localized-error-pages` configuration file.

Comment: thank you for the details but honestly I couldn't manage that as I need specific steps to follow and you were explaining in advance level (generalize). Kindly check my latest update and would appreciate if you provide me with direct clear steps to follow. Thank you.

Comment: @moderns I've added some examples and instructions.  Good luck.  `curl` will retrieve the custom error pages.

Comment: Thank you very much for the details. I followed your hints but still I need some input from you to solve this issue. Kindly check my new update. Thank you!

Comment: @moderns It looks like you want to use your own pages, so just do so.  I provided an example in the latest update.  At that point it becomes more of a programming issue than an Apache issue.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I need whenever the user enters long input in browser to redirect him to site/not_found.php, I can do easily the 404 error, but the 414 error doesn't work like 404 from sites-available :( Please have a look at my last update (Edit 2). Thanks.

Comment: @moderns Add the ErrorDocument specification for each error code you want to your configuration.  You will need one for 414. Verify the file in sites-available is the one linked to sites-enabled.  I'm past may experience as I don't encounter 414 errors.  Just remember to specify the URL path not the file path.

Comment: I tried ErrorDocument 414 /not_found.php, it didn't work :( <br> But ErrorDocument 404 /not_found.php and ErrorDocument 403 /not_found.php is working :( I didn't find any documentation online on how to make it for 414!